# ConfigSlurper is throwing error after Java upgrade 1.8

Tags: java, groovy

am using groovy 1.8.8 and java 1.7.0 
and the below code works fine

```
def config = new ConfigSlurper().parse(new File('conf/log4j.props').toURL())
PropertyConfigurator.configure(config.toProperties())
```

Recently Java upgrade was done.

```
Groovy Version: 1.8.8 JVM: 1.8.0 Vendor: IBM Corporation OS: Linux
```

When i run the script am getting the below errror

```
Caught: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.util.HashMap$Entry
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.util.HashMap$Entry
        at gk_feed_gen.run(gk_feed_gen.groovy:41)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.util.HashMap$Entry
        ... 1 more
```

I am aware, java.util.HashMap is not supported in Java 1.8. But i cant upgrade groovy as well.

What is the alternative solution to fix this issue in this case?

Comment: You just use config to retrieve the data of your properties directly, right?

Comment: You need groovy 3.4+ to use Java 8. Go back to Java 7 if you have to use a 5 year old version of groovy

Comment: That should read "you need groovy 2.3+ to use java 8"